# How to handle user corrections during intent confirmation?

Tags: java, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

We collect some user input during a dialog. At the end, we ask the user for confirmation: "Do you want to start XYZ with the parameters x, y and z?"

We want to provide the user the possibility to answer like "No, I want x to be parameter f". Thus, correcting his previous input.

Is there a best practice using the Java ASK-SDK?

Research just showed that this kind of support is recommended by Amazon:
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/alexa-design/adaptable.html#accept-corrections

However, there is no example code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom utterance for "no", and reprompt immediatly so the user is able to make corrections. So, instead of doing a slot confirmation, do it through the handler, and then reprompt the user (if you're using session attributes and dialogs) to force them to confirm or correct their input.

Following your example, if the user says "No, I want x to be parameter f", the "No" part is your first utterance to process. You'll need to validate they're in the part of the dialog when the input needs to be confirmed, that way you'll avoid getting a different "No" from triggering that intent. 
After you do that, you will reprompt to the user so the "I want x to be parameter f" triggers your other intent.

If you do it that way, you will be able to handle a lot of input corrections by recycling your already existing intents/utterances.